# Pass json value through a script and replace with output

Tags: json, xml, bash

Im trying to ingest IP ranges into SolarWinds with a label on each group of IP ranges associated with the service I want to label. Although I feel like there must be a much better way to do this because eventually, it will need to be in XML format.

```
<AddressGroups xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/IPAddressGroupsSchema.xsd">
  <AddressGroup enabled="true" description="Example">
    <Range from="13.107.6.152" to="13.107.6.153" />
  </AddressGroup>
  <AddressGroup enabled="true" description="Example 2">
    <Range from="150.224.0.0" to="150.224.131.255" />
    <Range from="150.224.140.0" to="150.224.255.255" />
  </AddressGroup>
```

Basically, I have a JSON file that i've pulled out all the un-needed information. I can't ingest CIDR addresses so I have a Go script that converts the CIDR notation to the IP range.

```
{
  "ips": [
    "13.107.6.152/31",
    "13.107.18.10/31",
    "13.107.128.0/22",
    "23.103.160.0/20",
    "40.96.0.0/13",
    "40.104.0.0/15",
    "52.96.0.0/14",
    "131.253.33.215/32",
    "132.245.0.0/16",
    "150.171.32.0/22",
    "191.234.140.0/22",
    "204.79.197.215/32",
    "2603:1006::/40",
    "2603:1016::/40",
    "2603:1026::/40",
    "2603:1026:200::/39",
    "2603:1026:400::/39",
    "2603:1026:600::/44",
    "2603:1026:620::/44",
    "2603:1026:800::/44",
    "2603:1026:820::/45",
    "2603:1036::/39",
    "2603:1036:200::/40",
    "2603:1036:400::/40",
    "2603:1036:600::/40",
    "2603:1036:800::/38",
    "2603:1036:c00::/40",
    "2603:1046::/37",
    "2603:1046:900::/40",
    "2603:1056::/40",
    "2603:1056:400::/40",
    "2603:1056:600::/40",
    "2603:1096::/38",
    "2603:1096:400::/40",
    "2603:1096:600::/40",
    "2603:1096:a00::/39",
    "2603:1096:c00::/40",
    "2603:10a6:200::/40",
    "2603:10a6:400::/40",
    "2603:10a6:600::/40",
    "2603:10a6:800::/40",
    "2603:10d6:200::/40",
    "2620:1ec:4::152/128",
    "2620:1ec:4::153/128",
    "2620:1ec:c::10/128",
    "2620:1ec:c::11/128",
    "2620:1ec:d::10/128",
    "2620:1ec:d::11/128",
    "2620:1ec:8f0::/46",
    "2620:1ec:900::/46",
    "2620:1ec:a92::152/128",
    "2620:1ec:a92::153/128",
    "2a01:111:f400::/48"
  ],
  "serviceArea": "Exchange",
  "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online"
}
```

There's a few more of these, but what i'm looking to do is loop through all of the ips, pass each one through [cidrls](https://github.com/nilium/cidrls) (a cidr conversion script), and replace them with the output, the ip range.

```
jq -r '.ips[]' msftServices.json | xargs -n1 cidrls
```

Output looks like this, 13.107.128.0 - 13.107.131.255

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is what you are after, but this will generate all of the necessary `<Range>` elements:

```
jq -r '.ips[]' msftServices.json | xargs -n1 cidrls | while read lower ignore upper; do echo "<Range from=\"$lower\" to=\"$upper\" />"; done
```